# How to install Realtek WLAN driver mt7921 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, realtek

Newer Lenovo laptops use the latest Realtek wifi card, wireless, WLAN,LTN, 8852BE for which the drivers are not available in current builds. How to install the Realtek WLAN driver mt7921 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Output of `sudo lshw -class network` for WLAN card:

```
*-network                 
    description: Wireless interface
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
    logical name: wlo1
    version: 00
    serial: d0:39:57:15:03:29
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=5.19.0-40-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.35 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
    resources: irq:113 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:b9b00000-b9bfffff
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
    logical name: enp4s0
    version: 15
    serial: e8:80:88:11:2b:e4
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-40-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
    resources: irq:72 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b9a04000-b9a04fff memory:b9a00000-b9a03fff
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `sudo lshw -class network` for WLAN card in the question shows `driver=rtw89_8852be` in the `Configuration:` line of the
`Wireless interface` section.

Do a USB tether with a smartphone: [Share a mobile connection by hotspot or tethering on Android](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9059108?hl=en).

After that, open the terminal and run the following commands.

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
sudo reboot
```

Now your wireless should now be working.

When Software Updater offers and installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, you must rebuild the driver:

```
cd rtw89
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
sudo reboot
```